# Error 500 in Laravel ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I got this error which I tried to fix with no success

in console

```
xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );//error
```

js

```
var data_id;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
  $(".edit_cost").click(function() {
    data_id = $(this).closest('div.portlet').attr('data-id');
  });
  $(".submit_cost").on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  var type = $(".cost_form").find('input[name="type"]').val();
  var cost = $(".cost_form").find('input[name="cost"]').val();
  var revenue = $(".cost_form").find('input[name="revenue"]').val();
  var profit = $(".cost_form").find('input[name="profit"]').val();
  var data =  $("form.cost_form").serialize();
  alert(data);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/partA-edit-cost",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
       // 'types': type,
       //'cost': cost,
       // 'revenue': revenue,
       // 'profit': profit,
       // 'data_id': data_id
      // 'data' : data
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      success: function(log) {
        console.log(log);
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Routes

```
 Route::post('/partA-edit-cost', 'CostController@editCost');
```

html

```
  @foreach($costs as $widget)
    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="3" data-sizey="3">
      <div class="portlet portlet-sortable light bordered ui-widget-content ui-resizable" data-id="{{$widget->id }}" data-find="{{$widget->id.$widget->name }}" data-name="{{ $widget->name }}">
        <div class="portlet-title ui-sortable-handle">
          <div class="caption font-green-sharp">
             <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
             <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase">{{ $widget->name }}</span>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-circle btn-default btn-sm remove">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove </a>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit_cost" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cost"><i class="fa fa-edit" data-button ="{{$widget->id}}"></i>Edit</button>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-default fullscreen" href="javascript:;"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div>{!! html_entity_decode($widget->api) !!}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  @endforeach



  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm cost" id="cost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" id="cost">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="width:500px;">
        <div class="portlet box white">
          <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
              <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>Edit Cost
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portlet-body form">
            <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
            <form action="/partA-edit-cost" class="cost_form" method="POST">

              <div class="form-actions top">
                <button type="submit" class="btn green submit_cost">Submit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancel</button>
              </div>
              <div class="form-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Type</label>
                    <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control type" placeholder="Enter Cost type">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Cost</label>
                    <input type="text" name ="cost" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Cost">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Revenue</label>
                  <input type="text" name="revenue" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Revenue">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Profit</label>
                  <input type="text" name="profit" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Profit">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Models\Cost;

class CostController extends Controller
{
public function editCost(Request $request)
{
    $type = $request->get('type');
    //$id = $request->get('id');
    $cost = COST::where('id', 3);
    $cost->type = "type";
    $cost->save();
    return \Response::json(['id' => $id,'type' => $type],200);
 }

}
```

Disable temporarily stuff inside the editCost method will remove the error

```
  public function editCost(Request $request) {
      echo "ok";

  }//returns on "ok " to the console;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is any error at `$cost = COST::where('id', 3);`, try changing it to

```
$cost = Cost::where('id', 3)->first();
```

`$cost = COST::where('id', 3);` results query scope not the Model, therefore you should add `first()` method, if no result matches your condition it will return null which can also result in the internal error issue since, you are calling `$cost->type` on the next line.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yeah I already tried this, this will actually save data to database, but does not remove the error in the console

Comment: Please paste the error trace we see what we can help

Answer (score 0):

In your code the variable $id is not defined in your return statement ( you have commented it out )

```
return \Response::json(['id' => $id,'type' => $type],200);
```

I think the code should look like:

```
$type = $request->get('type');
//$id = $request->get('id');
$cost = Cost::where('id', 3)->first();
$cost->type = "type";
$cost->save();
return \Response::json(['id' => 3,'type' => $type],200);
```

If that works you can use the dynamic $id and $type variables